# Android Jetpack Compose crashes when importing navigation compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

i am trying to build an Android JetPack Compose app. My problem is that when i import the bottom navigation dependency in build.gradle:

```
def nav_compose_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_compose_version"
```

When i run the application, it crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.steganograph, PID: 10389
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/foundation/Background;
    at androidx.compose.foundation.BackgroundKt.background-1xq40Q0(Background.kt:44)
    at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-biUpMIw(Surface.kt:101)
    at com.example.steganograph.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:19)
    at com.example.steganograph.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:175)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:238)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.compose.foundation.Background
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 64 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/InspectableParameter;
        ... 64 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.compose.ui.platform.InspectableParameter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.steganograph-7xhzN_I613wLPbtTa4vTGQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.steganograph-7xhzN_I613wLPbtTa4vTGQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 64 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Compose 1.0.0-alpha07, you must use Navigation Compose 1.0.0-alpha02 as the internals of Compose have changed so much as to make alpha01 (which was built against Compose 1.0.0-alpha06) incompatible.